# Botão compartilhar personalizado do facebook

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, facebook

Boa tarde.
Estou com problema para criar um botão de compartilhar do facebook que seja personalizado. Gostaria q me ajudassem a fazer um que funcionasse da forma q eu gostaria. Existe algumas coisas q eu queria que funcionassem diferente do que o que estou usando.

Por exemplo: [clique aqui](http://www.hercontabil.com.br/noticias/seja-bem-vindo-ao-nosso-site)

No link acima está meu site, podemos ver ali o botão "Facebook", que quando clicamos ele abre uma outra página e conseguimos finalizar o compartilhamento.

Porém eu queria que quando eu clicasse no botão do facebook ele abrisse uma tela (popup, modal), e ali estivessem os dados da noticia corretamente.
No botão atual a imagem que o facebook reconhece é sempre a mesma, e não de acordo com a notícia.

Caso não tenha ficado muito claro o que quero aprender a fazer, acesse o link de um produto do walmart (qualquer produto do site deles, lado esquerdo do produto está o botão de facebook, quando clicar ali vai abrir o botão de compartilhar)

No site do walmart, ao clicar no botão COMPARTILHAR ele abre a modal e lá contem a foto correta do produto, o nome dele, descrição, e etc.

O código do meu botão atual:

```
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Botão:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.hercontabil.com.br/noticias/<%# Eval("Noticia_Pagina")%>" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="link_rede_social facebook fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.hercontabil.com.br/noticias/<%# Eval("Noticia_Pagina")%>">Facebook</a></div>
```

Informações adicionais: o site já possui a tag og:image, e etc... mesmo assim o script não traz a imagem da noticia.
Também já entrei no OG Sharing Debbuger do facebook, apresenta seguinte mensagem: Image Unavailable
Provided og:image, http://www.hercontabil.com.br/sistema/noticias/1noticia_teste.png could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.

O problema é que a imagem não tem mais de 8mb, e o caminho q eles especificam no erro não está correto tbm.

Comment: O seu site usa ASP ou PHP?

Comment: Você está usando a API do facebook neh? Pelo endereço, parece que o sistema está ignorando uma barra depois do número 1 (Que imagino ser a página). Provavelmente o erro está acontecendo por causa que ele está pegando o endereço errado. Eu tive uma certa dificuldade pra fazer funcionar uma vez em um blog. No botão tenta acrescentar uma barra depois da variável da página.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, você poderá adotar a seguinte abordagem:

Criar uma função javascript que receba a url da notícia e atribuir a chamada da função no botão personalizado.

```
function shareFacebook(url){

        var w = 630;
        var h = 360;

        var left = screen.width/2 - 630/2;
        var top = screen.height/2 - 360/2;

        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url, 'Compartilhar no facebook', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, ' + 'menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+ ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
 }
```

Exemplo de chamada:

```
<button onclick="shareFacebook('http://google.com.br');">Compartilhar no facebook</button>
```